# How can I put superLink for email in itextpdf?

Tags: itext

I have to place a email address in a cell of a table in itextPdf,  it is required to when I click the email address, outlook window can opened and email can be sent directly by adding some message to it. Below is my code, and when i click the email address, it doesn't work, who have some advice about it, thanks!

```
Chunk mail = new Chunk("xxxx@xx.com", font).setAnchor("xxxx@xx.com");
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
            cell.addElement(mail);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Chunk mail = new Chunk("xxxx@xx.com", font).setAnchor("mailto:xxxx@xx.com");
```

It seems like you forgot to add the `mailto:` in front of the mail address.

Comment: thanks a lot, with your help I have solved this problem.

Comment: In that case, please accept the answer so that other people can see that the question was answered. (Check the check mark to the left of the answer.)